# Displaying and linking information in an array

Tags: php

I'm using the following script to pull information from Google Suggestions:

```
<?php
function getKeywordSuggestionsFromGoogle($keyword) {
    $keywords = array();
    $data = file_get_contents('http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&client=firefox&hl=en-US&q='.urlencode($keyword));
    if (($data = json_decode($data, true)) !== null) {
        $keywords = $data[1];
    }

    return $keywords;
}

var_dump(getKeywordSuggestionsFromGoogle('business'));
?>
```

This is what shows when accessing the PHP file in the browser:

```
array(10) { [0]=> string(14) "business cards" [1]=> string(22) "business letter format" [2]=> string(16) "business insider" [3]=> string(15) "business casual" [4]=> string(13) "business plan" [5]=> string(22) "business plan template" [6]=> string(13) "business week" [7]=> string(14) "business ideas" [8]=> string(17) "business for sale" [9]=> string(8) "business" }
```

I need to figure out how to do two things:

1. Display the information correctly on my webpage so that it looks like this:

   business cards, business letter format, and so on
2. I need each of the keywords linked to my domain like this:

   [business cards](http://www.mysite.com/keywords/business-cards), [business letter format](http://www.mysite.com/keywords/business-letter-format), and so on

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.............

```
<?php
function getKeywordSuggestionsFromGoogle($keyword) {
    $keywords = array();
    $data = file_get_contents('http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&client=firefox&hl=en-US&q='.urlencode($keyword));

    if (($data = json_decode($data, true)) !== null) {
        $keywords = $data[1];
    }

    return $keywords;
}

$result = getKeywordSuggestionsFromGoogle('business');


foreach($result as $key => $r)

  {

     echo '<a href = "http://www.mysite.com/keywords/'. $r.'">'. $r .'</a>';

   }
 ?>
```

If you want to refer to some links you can put that `echo $r` in  between `<a href="#"><?php echo $r ?></a>`

Comment: That worked except there weren't any commas.  Also, I tried adding `echo $r` between the code like you said but then it gave this error:  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/envision/public_html/keywords.php on line 18`  Here's line 18:  `<a href="http://www.mysite.com/keywords/<?php echo $r ?>"><?php echo $r ?></a>, ;`

Comment: Got the same error as above using that.  This is exactly what I have for line 18:  `<a href="mysite.com/keywords/';. echo $r.'/'.echo $r.'"</a>;`

Comment: Still showing the error about `unexpected '<'` which I'm guessing is the first one right before `a href`

Comment: This is exactly what I have on line 18:  `<a href="http://www.mysite.com/keywords/'.$r.'/'.$r.'"</a>;`